# Error during "build" phase of GitHub Pages deployment

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

This is my first dive into programming and I am trying to deploy my GitHub Pages site. I am feeling very lost trying to troubleshoot this on my own. Does anyone have any advice? I am receiving  Conversion error:

```
Jekyll::Converters::Scss encountered an error while converting 'assets/css/style.scss':
43
               No such file or directory @ dir_chdir - /github/workspace/docs
```

Comment: It looks like you have configured your [publishing source](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site#publishing-from-a-branch) to be the `docs` directory, but you don't actually have such a directory.

Comment: I personally have found GitHub Pages on the backend to be too finicky so I compile the code on my machine and just upload the static HTML. Does your code compile on your machine correctly? I've found malware in free GitHub Pages templates so watch out. Also too you can run JavaScript using GitHub Actions and you can actually just program your website in React.JS.

Comment: @CaleMcCollough Yes, when loading the html file in the browser from my local drive it works as it should. Unfortunately, GitHub Pages must be used for this project.

Comment: You can program your website in React, and use GitHub Actions to compile your webpage. It's not very difficult. Jekyll is cool, I used it for years, but it's too limited and GitHub pages is always a hassle. With React you can make sites just as easy, only you can use JavaScript so you can expand to a more powerful website & not deal with the hassles of GitHub Page's build system.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your pages config on your repo is pointing to the /root instead of /docs

[image: check this out]

Hope it solves your issue!